# Motor response is lagging

Tags: arduino-nano, motor, midi

I've got a DC motor connected to an Arduino Nano, L298N H-Bridge and a 12v Power supply. I'm trying to make it respond to incoming MIDI data a bit quicker. Right now, it seems awfully slow, and lags in response to quick value changes. I'm using MIDI to send data into my Arduino, so my baud rate is limited to 31250.

The issue is mainly with my DAW (Ableton), as my motor responds quickly when I try to control it with a fader on my MIDI keyboard.

Note: I'm also using a potentiometer and a capacitive touch sensor in this code. I'll try to simplify it as much as I can so I can isolate the issue
Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> // MIDI Input
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>
#include <MIDI.h> // MIDI Output
#define txPin 1
#define rxPin 4

SoftwareSerial midiSerial (rxPin, txPin);

const byte touchSend    = 2;//Send pin for Capacitance Sensing Circuit (Digital 7)
const byte motorPWM     = 3;
const byte motorDown    = 5;
const byte motorUp      = 6;
const byte touchReceive = 7; //Receive pin for Capacitance Sensing Circuit (Digital 8)
const byte wiper        = 7; //Position of fader relative to GND (Analog 0)

int incomingCommand;
int incomingNote;
int incomingVelocity;
byte motorSpeed = 75; // Raise if the fader is too slow (0-255)
byte minimumCp  = 200; // Raise if the fader is too sensitive (0-16383)
byte tolerance  = 10; // Raise if the fader is too shaky (0-1023)
double faderMax = 0; //Value read by fader's maximum position (0-1023)
double faderMin = 0; //Value read by fader's minimum position (0-1023)
bool touched = false; //Is the fader currently being touched?
long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounceDelay    = 10;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers
int lastfaderValue    = 0;

byte ch1Vol = 224;
byte fullVel = 127;
byte ch_1 = 1;
byte Db_1 = 1;

CapacitiveSensor touch = CapacitiveSensor(touchReceive, touchSend);
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

void setup() {
  touch.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  midiSerial.begin(31250);
  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI);
  while (!Serial);
  pinMode(motorDown, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorUp, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rxPin, INPUT );
  pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(motorPWM, motorSpeed);
  calibrateFader(); }

void calibrateFader() {
  digitalWrite(motorUp, HIGH);
  analogWrite(motorPWM, 100);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(motorUp, LOW);
  faderMax = analogRead(wiper) - tolerance;
  digitalWrite(motorDown, HIGH);
  analogWrite(motorPWM, 100);
  delay(300);
  digitalWrite(motorDown, LOW);
  faderMin = analogRead(wiper) + tolerance; }

void loop() {
  int faderPos = analogRead(wiper);
  int faderMIDI = faderPos / 8;
  int faderHiResMIDI = ((faderPos *16) - 8191);
  while ( midiSerial.available() > 0 ) {
    int commandByte = midiSerial.read();
    int noteByte = midiSerial.read();
    byte velocityByte = midiSerial.read();
    midiSerial.write( commandByte);
    midiSerial.write( noteByte);
    midiSerial.write( velocityByte);
    incomingCommand = commandByte;
    incomingNote = noteByte;
    incomingVelocity = velocityByte*8; }
    
 { int totalCp =  touch.capacitiveSensor(30); 
 if ( (millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    if (totalCp <= minimumCp) { touched = false; // Not Touching Fader 
      if (incomingCommand == ch1Vol) { updateFader(incomingVelocity); } }
    if ((faderPos == lastfaderValue) && (totalCp > minimumCp)) { touched = true; // Touching Fader
      MIDI.sendNoteOn(Db_1, fullVel, ch_1);
      digitalWrite(motorDown, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorUp, LOW); }
    if (((faderPos > lastfaderValue+1) or (faderPos < lastfaderValue-1)) && (totalCp > minimumCp)) { touched = true; // Moving Fader
      MIDI.sendPitchBend(faderHiResMIDI, ch_1);
      digitalWrite(motorDown, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorUp, LOW); }
    lastfaderValue = faderPos;  
    lastDebounceTime = millis(); //set the current time
} } }

void updateFader(int position) {     //Function to move fader to a specific position between 0-1023 if it's not already there
  if (position < analogRead(wiper) - tolerance && position > faderMin && !touched) {
    digitalWrite(motorDown, HIGH);
    while (position < analogRead(wiper) - tolerance && !touched) {}; //Loops until motor is done moving
    digitalWrite(motorDown, LOW); }
  else if (position > analogRead(wiper) + tolerance && position < faderMax && !touched) {
    digitalWrite(motorUp, HIGH);
    while (position > analogRead(wiper) + tolerance && !touched) {}; //Loops until motor is done moving
    digitalWrite(motorUp, LOW); } }
```

Comment: It probably because those `while() {}` (wait until...) codes that are blocking.

Comment: About what lack are we talking here exactly? Is it the delay between sending a command and the fader starting to move? Or is it the fader not reacting directly when it already received a command? From your code the former should be rather short (a bit more than 10ms I think), while the latter will be a bit greater than the time that the motor needs to drive the fader to its previously commanded position (because of the while loop).

Comment: There's a fundamental flaw in your serial reading code. Read: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: Good point. @zRockafellow You are checking for more than zero bytes being available, but then you read 3 bytes. You cannot be sure, that all these bytes where already received. Maybe just check for 3 bytes being available

Comment: I tried replacing the while() codes with if, but I found that the motor stopped responding to data completely. I'll try rewriting that section without any while loops.

Comment: @Majenko I changed the '0' to a '2' in the Serial reading code. This made my motor move a tiny bit after receiving data, and stop responding completely. Change the '2' back to '0' & I can move the motor freely again.

Comment: @chrisl The fader's not reacting directly when it receives a command. It's receiving a number between 0 and 127, and if I have any quick movements, the data coming into serial skips quite a bit of information to get to the new value, which makes my motor jump around as well

Comment: I'm wondering if simply getting a faster processor would do it? I'll try running this same code, but instead of using an Arduino Nano, I'll use a Mega. Or perhaps it's time to get a teensy

Comment: You have to just read the serial properly. Read one byte (the command byte) then use that to determine how many other bytes should be read, then read those in one at a time as they arrive. Only once all the bytes for a command have arrived do you act on it.

Comment: your code shows unclear thinking ... for instance, every `if` statement in `updateFader` contains `&& !touched` ... just test that first on its own .... actually, you don't even have to test it because of `touched = false;` just before `updateFader` is called

Comment: I took out the boolean 'touched' part of the code entirely - Didn't make a difference to the functionality, but thanks for pointing that out. The motor still runs smoothest when I use the code "Serial.available > '0'". I've tried every combination of the number 0-3, and that one is definitely the smoothest

Comment: @Majenko, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If it works best when reading the Serial as is, is that still not the proper way?